# Partial derivative of summation and tranpose

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am stuck with the partial derivative of summation of a variable and want to know is there any partial derivative that calculates to its transpose?
I am attaching figures for reference. Please help. In this expression, i want to calculate the partial derivative of this equation w.r.t $w_k$:$$\sum_{k=1}^nw_k(n)\mathbf{\phi}\{\mathbf{x}(n),\,\mathbf{c}_k(n),\,\sigma_k(n)\}$$
And can any partial derivative calculates to the tranpose which give this is as the answer?$$\mathbf{\Psi}(n)=[\phi\{\mathbf{x}(n,\,\mathbf{c}_1,\,\sigma_1)\},\,\phi\{\mathbf{x}(n,\,\mathbf{c}_2,\,\sigma_2)\},\,\cdots,\,\phi\{\mathbf{x}(n,\,\mathbf{c}_1,\,\sigma_1)\}]^T$$

Comment: Welcome to math.se. I've changed your figures to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as we prefer, but you may want to double-check my bolding. I'm also unsure whether my $\phi$ (`\phi`) was meant to be something else: the image you provided looked almost as if it were using either $\emptyset$ (`\emptyset`) or $\varnothing$ (`\varnothing`), but that can't be right.

Comment: Phi is just a function with three parameters.

Comment: Can you clarify: you are looking for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \omega_k}$?  If so, then since $\phi$ doesn't rely on $\omega_k$ the answer is just the summation without the $\omega_k$, since that partial would just treat $\phi$ as a constant.  Did you mean wrt $n$?  That would be harder

Comment: No I want it w.r.t W(k). But my problem is that I don't want summation in the final answer and I want its answer to be calculated to the second image shown above where there is a transpose also.

Comment: I see.  So you are looking for $n$ partial derivatives, each one with respect to a separate $w_k$?

Comment: Yeah may be. If you could help me with the this answer as a transpose.?